# What is wrong with these Tomcat database connection pooling configuration

Tags: connection-pooling, tomcat8

From last two years on tomcat I am using this configuration for database connection pooling in tomcat

```
<Resource auth="Container" 
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          logAbandoned="true" 
          maxActive="100" 
          maxIdle="30" 
          maxWait="10000"
          name="jdbc/maindb" 
          password="xxxxx" 
          removeAbandoned="true" 
          removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/maindb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"
        connectionProperties="useEncoding=true;"
        username="sqladmin" validationQuery="select 1"/>
```

On production server, from last one month, with this configuration - suddenly tomcat stop responding to any requests. And results in timeout. There is no errors in logs, but as soon as I shutdown tomcat a huge amount of error log comes, which seems to show some kind of deadlock in database connections.

To rectify it, I used database connection pooling configuration from http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html . After using this configuration, now I face two problems, on production, either a table lock occurs even after using INNODB engine, or some queries start returning empty result set even when query is perfectly fine.

```
<Resource name="jdbc/maindb"
      auth="Container"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
      testWhileIdle="true"
      testOnBorrow="true"
      testOnReturn="false"
      validationQuery="SELECT 1"
      validationInterval="30000"
      timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
      maxActive="100"
      minIdle="10"
      maxWait="10000"
      initialSize="10"
      removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
      removeAbandoned="true"
      logAbandoned="true"
      minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000"
      jmxEnabled="true"
      jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;
        org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer"
      username="sqladmin"
      password="xxxxx"
      driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/maindb"/>
```

In case of first configuration, after shutting down tomcat following error logs start coming

```
04-Feb-2015 20:44:46.048 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
04-Feb-2015 20:44:46.049 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
04-Feb-2015 20:44:46.100 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
04-Feb-2015 20:44:46.151 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service Catalina
04-Feb-2015 20:44:46.157 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.unload Waiting for 81 instance(s) to be deallocated for Servlet [dispatcher]
04-Feb-2015 20:44:47.158 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.unload Waiting for 81 instance(s) to be deallocated for Servlet [dispatcher]
04-Feb-2015 20:44:48.160 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.unload Waiting for 81 instance(s) to be deallocated for Servlet [dispatcher]
04-Feb-2015 20:44:48.260 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Tue Feb 03 18:26:26 UTC 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
04-Feb-2015 20:44:48.307 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Feb 03 18:26:24 UTC 2015]; root of context hierarchy
04-Feb-2015 20:44:48.310 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ExecutorConfigurationSupport.shutdown Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskExecutor'
04-Feb-2015 20:44:48.329 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] is still processing a request that has yet to finish. This is very likely to create a memory leak. You can control the time allowed for requests to finish by using the unloadDelay attribute of the standard Context implementation. Stack trace of request processing thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:582)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:439)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:360)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:118)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1412)
 com.myproj.dao.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:41)
```

And in second case following error logs comes, while doing certain operation

```
22-Jan-2015 16:36:04.077 SEVERE [http-apr-8080-exec-2] com.myproj.dao.cart.impl.VisitorCartDaoImpl.addCartItem Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
 java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:996)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2530)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1907)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2141)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2077)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2062)
    at com.myproj.dao.cart.impl.VisitorCartDaoImpl.addCartItem(VisitorCartDaoImpl.java:96)
```

Is there anything wrong with the configuration or with the database? I am using MySQL 5.6 as the database and on production, mySQL is running on amazon RDS. And I am using tomcat 8.0.15

Comment: I have the same exact issue. Did you ever figure out what this was?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue? I am facing the same issue. I'm curious to know the fix.

Comment: As far as I can recall, there was some issue with JDBC code used in some methods. Connections were not getting closed in correct fashion. Pooling configuration was fine.